# Overhead of data types in cassandra

Tags: types, cassandra, blob, storage, diskspace

Where can I find information about overhead of data types in cassandra?
I am interested about blob, text, uuid, timeuuid data types. Does a blob type store a value with the length of the blob data? If yes then which type of the length it is using (int, bigint)? 
If I want to store 80 bits how much of disk space will be used for it? If I want to store 64 bits is it better to use bigint?

Answer (score 2):

I think these overheads are completely negligible, because they will be heavily compensated by the compression.